# В чём разница между LinkedList<T> и LinkedListNode<T>?

Tags: c#, linked-list

Читаю о ***LinkedList***, затем в коде появляется ***LinkedListNode***. В книге используется, но не объясняется что это.

```
LinkedList<int> numbers = new LinkedList<int>();

// Заполнение List<int> с помощью метода AddFirst
foreach (int number in new int[] {10, 8, 6, 4, 2})
{
    numbers.AddFirst(number);
}

// Итерация с использованием инструкции for
Console.WriteLine("Iterating using a for statement:");
for (LinkedListNode<int> node = numbers.First; node != null; node = node.Next)
{
    int number = node.Value;
    Console.WriteLine(number);
}

// Итерация с использованием инструкции foreach
Console.WriteLine("\nIterating using a foreach statement:");
foreach (int number in numbers)
{
    Console.WriteLine(number);
}
```

Comment: `LinkedList` - это набор элементов `LinkedListNode`

Comment: вообще если хочешь понять эту тему лучше отстранись от подобных примеров с "навороченными циклами" и тому подобному. 

Вот хороший учебник по шарпу metanit и статья о связном списке в нем: https://metanit.com/sharp/algoritm/2.1.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LinkedListNode - это элемент LinkedList (линкед лист переводится как "связный список", а Node - узел, то есть LinkedListNode это "узел связного списка").

Ты не можешь просто так в линкед лист запихивать элементы встроенных типов, например int или string. У элементов также должна быть ссылка на следующий элемент (в этом то и суть связного списка), и тебе уже надо создать свой объект, который будет хранить данные (value, Data, или еще как-то по-другому), а также ссылку на след. элемент (Next)